# Unicode Codepoint as a long?

Tags: unicode

I am using a library which requires that I apply a Unicode code-point as a long.
I am using C++.

I'm not sure I'm doing this right.  I have already looked over this forum and google and I just can't understand the answers. Nothing answers this directly.

In my code I am using a function to get a Glyph ID from an object containing font metrics.

eg.

```
int FontMetrics->GetGlyphID(long unicode_codepoint).
```

Theoretically I should be able to do something like this. Just a simple static cast.  But my function is returning Zero because I'm applying the unicode codepoint incorrectly.  I'm just not sure how.  Is my example below correct or is there another correct way of doing this?  O a am using C++ not C.

```
char my_character = 'a';

int GlyphID = FontMetrics->GetGlyphID( (long)my_character) )
```

Comment: Just stop using a library that both looks and acts flaky.  Or use a telephone.

Comment: We'll need a small but complete program to figure out what you're trying to do. But I can already tell you that **you cannot assume that one code point corresponds to one particular glyph**.

Comment: May I ask why.  I would assume that one codepoint represents only one Unicode value (say UTF-8).  The Glyph ID (based on the current font) corresponds to a specific Glyph.  Not sure what you're saying here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly converting to unicode long (at least for ASCII). If we look at the API for PoDoFo, here's what we see:

> virtual long PoDoFo::PdfFontMetrics::GetGlyphId   (   long
>     lUnicode    )   const
>
> Get the glyph id for a unicode character **in the current font**.
>
> Parameters lUnicode: the unicode character value
>
> Returns: the glyhph (sic) id for the character **or 0 if the glyph was not found.**

So my best guess is that you don't have the current font set properly. Why don't you give us a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example** of the code that isn't working.

Comment: Well, you have answered the question.  That's really all I need to know. As for how I've set this up, the code is long and needs to be broken down for me to post it so for now I'll mark this as solved and repost a new question if I can't figure it out.  I just wanted to check whether I have referenced the Unicode codepoint the correct way.

Comment: If you are keen to look at this ongoing issue I have created a new thread under "Extracting GlyphID in Podofo?" .  As my original question has been answered on this thread I've started a new one to address the ongoing issue. Being a Podofo question I will be interested if anyone can answer it as there's not allot of examples out there on Podofo.